# App Thining - How it works if full assets are not provided by developer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

App Thining conveys that, automatically it creates variants of assets according to device specifications.
I want to know if full assets not provided or for ex., missed 1x images, then 4s user will get 2x images or wont get any images as 4s works on 1x images.

Comment: The user is confused about how to use 1x images whereas it's no longer required by any devices.

Comment: if 1x images won't be available assets won't throw the error

Answer (score 1):

[image]

4s without Ratina display *(No longer available)* uses the 1x images & 4s with Ratina display uses 2x.
**NOTE:** whereas 4s without ratina production has been closed by Apple since few years ago and not in use by any users anymore.
So 1x is not required, 2x will be used in 4s, 5 & 6 devices, whereas 3x will be used on 6+ devices.

Comment: The 4s have the Retina display. All the iPhone after the 3GS have it.

Comment: Ya. so 1x images are not required any longer.

Comment: please find about image resolution info from : https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/iOS_Design.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index

Comment: Thanks Friends. But I just want to know that For ex. if I have universal app , and I am not providing 1x images then what will happen if user is installing the app for ipad 1st gen/ ipad mini, he will get images or not

Comment: No user won't get images in early generations of 3rd, for those you will require 1x, but for iPhones you won't require 1x. You should mention that in your question clearly that you want to consider iPad's of early generations, but you mentioned 4s and you down vote my correct answer, that was so wrong.

Comment: @KiranJasvanee sorry sir, that was by mistake. But thanks for good answer

Comment: please uproot if you get satisfied